# Plotly 'Download as png' resizing image when used in RShiny application

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm using `plotly` package for `R` to display some large graphs in my `shiny` application, the graphs display nicely as intended. However, when I click the "Download as png" button, the downloaded .png has been resized. [here is a demo of this behavior](https://michael-bird-94.shinyapps.io/rodeexplorer/).

How can I specify the resolution for the exported plot?

Here is a minimal example that demonstates the issue by having a really long title that gets clipped on download

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Plotly Download demo"),

                plotlyOutput("demoPlotly"))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$demoPlotly <- renderPlotly({
    #make an arbritrary graph with a long title
    p <- iris %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "This is a really long title to demo my problem of plotly resizing my downloaded output")
    ggplotly(p)

  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The downloaded graph looks like this:
[image: Clipped plotly graph]

Comment: I have the same issue. but know of no solution.

Comment: @Ameya Technophobe01 has added an answer you might find helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael,

Take a look at `plotly_IMAGE()`. [Version 4.7.1]. The function does allow you to specify width and height for the saved image. For example 800 by 600.

Regarding your example, I have provided an example of how you might modify the layout to accommodate the title wrapping. Note the changes the margin and padding. I also inserted a call to `plotly_IMAGE` to provide a simplified example of its usage - it slows things down as it is in line with the plot generation. I'd recommend you add a button and separate out from image display.

Hope this helps

Take care
T.

---

### Pre-requisite - Plotly Credentials:

To use this plotly example you need to register and obtain a `plotly api` key. Once obtained you need add these entries to your `~/.Renviron` file.
**Ref**: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/

#### Example .Renviron file entries

```
plotly_username="xxxxx"
plotly_api_key="xxxxxx"
```

---

### Example Code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

wrapper <- function(x, ...) {
  paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")
}

# Example usage wrapper(my_title, width = 20)

my_title <- "This is a really long title to demo my problem of plotly resizing my downloaded output"

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Plotly Download demo"), plotlyOutput("demoPlotly"))

pal <- c("blue", "red", "green")
pal <- setNames(pal, c("virginica", "setosa", "versicolor"))

layout <- list(title = wrapper(my_title, width = 60),
               xaxis = list(title = "Petal Length"),
               yaxis = list(title = "Petal Width"),
               margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 100, pad = 4))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$demoPlotly <- renderPlotly({
    # make an arbitrary graph with a long title
    p <- iris %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length,
              y = ~Petal.Width,
              color = ~Species,
              colors = pal,
              mode = "markers",
              type = "scatter") %>%
      layout(autosize = F,
             title = layout$title,
             xaxis = layout$xaxis,
             yaxis = layout$yaxis,
             margin = layout$margin)
    p$elementId <- NULL
    # Example usage of plotly image
    plotly_IMAGE(p, 
                 width = 800, 
                 height = 600, 
                 format = "png", 
                 scale = 1, 
                 out_file = "output.png")
    p
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

### Screen Shot Image - screen capture

[image: Screen Shot Image]

---

### Plotly save - screen click

[image: Plot save as png Image]

---

### plotly_IMAGE() save image output 800 by 600

[image]

Comment: Hi Technophobe, this works beautifully. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelBird Great, always happy to help. Take care.

Comment: @Technophobe01 Do you need a Plotly account for to be able to resize the images?

Comment: @Ameya The example does require a Plotly account **though not a paid account**. I just checked I had my credentials setup via '.Renviron'

Comment: While I was unsuccessfully using the above code without an account, I tinkered with it to notice that just adding `pad=4` to the `margin` gave me satisfactory results!

Comment: @Ameya - thanks, I updated the answer to note you need to setup a plotly account, and add your credentials to your ~/.Renviron file.